# My divs are piling up underneath each other

Tags: css

I was doing some CSS, and my divs keep piling up underneath each other. I tried using position on them but it didn't work. My work is below. The picture I have in it will not be available to you as it is from my computer, but I hope you can get the idea of what my issue is(The sitelingo and Capture12 are the ones piling up):

```css
#logomain {
  font-family: museo-sans-rounded, sans-serif;
  font-size: 33px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-left: 470px;
}

#sitelingo {
  font-family: museo-sans-rounded, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 232px;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

#barone {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #0A4076;
}

#bartwo {
  postition: fixed;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #0A4076;
}

#login {
  padding-left: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Duolingo</title>
</head>


<body>

  <div id="barone">

    <div id="logomain"> duolingo </div>

  </div>

  <div id="bartwo">

    <div id="sitelingo"> Site language: English </div>

    <div id="login"> <img src="images/Capture12.png" /> </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does your final result need to look like?

Comment: The CSS is very messy and it's unclear what you want this to look like. You need to provide a description or image of how you want this to look like. Also, share the Capture12.png image or dimensions.

Comment: They stack up on each other only if the screen width goes below a certain width. Maybe you need to apply [responsive design](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp) to your website or use a css framework (e.g. Bootstrap)

Comment: Capture12 is just a small picture that is no more than 200px by 100px. It is a login button screenshot

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues:

You set a position:fixed to #barone. This will position the element relative to the actual screen.

You have elements positioned absolute, when the screen resizes, it will overlap with other elements

A padding left is set on your logo, this makes it out of viewpoint

Maybe you may want something as depicted below

```css
#logomain {
  font-family: museo-sans-rounded, sans-serif;
  font-size: 33px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top: 13px;
  /* padding-left: 470px;*/
}

#sitelingo {
  font-family: museo-sans-rounded, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  /*padding-left: 232px;*/
  padding-top: 24px;
}

#bar_container {
  background-color: #0A4076;
}

#barone {
  /* position: fixed;*/
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #0A4076;
  display: inline-block;
}

#bartwo {
  postition: fixed;
  float: right;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #0A4076;
}
#bartwo *{
display:inline-block;
}
#login {
position:relative;
  /*padding-left: 400px;
  position: absolute; */
  vertical-align: middle;

  top:0;
}
#login img{
width:100px;
height:100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Duolingo</title>
</head>


<body>
  <div id="bar_container">
    <div id="barone">

      <div id="logomain"> duolingo </div>

    </div>

    <div id="bartwo">
      <div id="sitelingo"> Site language: English </div>
      <div id="login"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRgKSOJmOr8tNodELaCLPrI1T2XE7iwrpuxPDGuFeoJwlJC4AVKZw" /> </div>

    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```